# Loading plugin CSS with Encore/Symcony2

Tags: css, reactjs, symfony, webpack, frontend

I am having issues trying to wrap my head around loaders with Encore. Let's take a random plugin for example (https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker).

As per the documentation one should first install the plugin using either npm or yarn. Then, you just have to use the `import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';` on top of your component file. Then, it also says that you should add `import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';` and this is where I am having issues.

Before explaining what I've done I must say that the plugin itself is working because if I include the CSS directly (in the HTML using the  tag) it works perfectly.

Here is my current `webpack.config.js`:

```
// webpack.config.js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')    
    .setPublicPath('/build')    
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/App.js')
    .enableSassLoader()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel(function (babelConfig) {
        babelConfig.presets.push('es2017');
    })

    // I have tried to use separate .addLoader using css-loader
    // and style-loader, I have also tried to use them together in an array ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    // also tried without the .addLoader directive here, and using:
    //
    // import 'style-loader!css-loader!react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
    // 
    .addLoader({ test: /\.css/, loader: "css-loader"})
    .enableReactPreset()
;
var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.watchOptions = {poll: true, ignored: /node_modules/};
module.exports = config;
```

The common errors that I am getting everytime I try to run the `./node_modules/.bin/encore dev --watch` commands are:

**1. If I try to use theimport 'style-loader!css-loader!react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css':**

[image: Using the loaders directly in the import]

**2. If I use the .addLoader({ test: /.css/, loader: "css-loader"}):**
[image]
(Similar issue happens if I use style-loader!css-loader and/or on an array)

Besides all of this I have to clarify that I have installed the css-loader and the style-loader dependencies.

My question would be, what is the proper way to load css files without having to use the old  tag using Symfony2 (3.3 in this case...) and Encore? Or should I leave Encore and use plain webpack/babel from scratch?

Comment: Just as an FYI, I decided in the meantime to dump Encore and just create my .babelrc and my webpack.config.js from scratch and importing the css now works perfectly.